# MySQL STR_TO_DATE() not working with LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, datetime, format, load-data-infile

Can anyone explain why the following generates `Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '11/18/2013 4:49:42 PM' for column 'timestamp' at row 1`?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\\\\file.txt'
INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
SET timestamp=STR_TO_DATE(@timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s %p');
```

Here is the first line from the text file:
`0  b4:52:7d:62:dd:83   -45 11/18/2013 4:49:42 PM`
(the tabs don't seem to be displaying properly, but they are there).

I've tested the following query and it works like a charm:
`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/18/2013 4:49:42 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s %p');`

So I can't figure out why it doesn't work as part of the larger query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs because data is first inserted, then used with the SET, since the date you are giving is not in the right format to be inserted into a 'datetime' typed field, the value gets lost.

In my sample I used this (| as a delimiter is easier to see in pasting here):

```
#cat /tmp/file
0|b4:52:7d:62:dd:83|-45|11/18/2013 4:49:42 PM|

LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/file'
INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s %p');

CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) default NULL,
  `mac` text,
  `offset` int(11) default NULL,
  `date` datetime default NULL
)
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'm a little bit confused about your code though... If it's a solution I don't see what changed (my_table already exists in my case).

Comment: Mine isn't a solution, it just shows that the problem isn't with what you are doing, rather that "date" field cannot get your value, if you change date to text_date (for example), and use SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@textdate, ...) it will work